# Sharing a singleton timer between two different qmls

Tags: timer, qml, singleton, signals

I am trying to use a singleton timer between two different QML files.

I wanted to achieve two expectations.

1. Creating a singleton timer (countdown timer) and share it between to QML files.
2. Transferring the left over countdown value from one qml (`Actpopup.qml`) to other qml (`Body.qml`).

I have tried in the below way:

#### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import "qrc:///timerFile"

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 1200
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Body {}

    SosPopupActivationReq {}
    
    TonTimerSingle {
        // I think one error related to singleton is because of this syntax
    }
}
```

#### Body.qml

```
Item {
    id: root

    Button {
        id: qoBtn
        implicitWidth: 162
        implicitHeight: 162
        text: "QO"

        background: Rectangle {
            id:sosBtnBg
            color: countdownTimer.running ? "#cc0000" : "#bfc6d0"
        }

        contentItem: Item {
            ColumnLayout {
                anchors.fill: parent
                Image {
                    width:50
                    height: 50
                    source: (!qoActive) ? "images/rectangle-1694.png" : "images/oval-1694.png"
                    Text {
                        text:qsTr("Hi")
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
                }
                Text{
                    text: qoBtn.text
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
                }
            }
        }

        onClicked: {
            console.error("======> Clicked <========")
            var popupComponent = Qt.createComponent("Actpopup.qml")
            if(popupComponent.status !== Component.Ready) {
                if( popupComponent.status === Component.Error)
                    console.debug("Error:"+ popupComponent.errorString());
                return; // or maybe throw
            }
            var popup2 = popupComponent.createObject(qoBtn);
            popup2.open()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Actpopup.qml

```
Popup {
    id: actPopup
    
    RoundButton {
        id:closeBtn
        text: "X"
        x: 55
        y: 46
        width: 40
        height: 40
        onClicked: {
            // Wanted to send intimation to body that Act popup got closed and left over count down value to be display on button
            console.error("Closed the POPUP==========>")
        }
    }

    Slider {
        id:control
        value: 0
        Layout.topMargin: 20
        Layout.leftMargin: 154
        onPositionChanged: {
            backgroundText.opacity = 1-position
            if(control.visualPosition === 1.0) {
                console.error("POP Activated====>")
                // when the user drags the slider handle till the end, i want to send a trigger to start the singleton timer
                console.error("SOS Activated====>")
            }
        }

        background: Rectangle {
            x: control.leftPadding
            y: control.topPadding + control.availableHeight / 2 - height / 2
            implicitWidth: 331
            implicitHeight: 68
            width: control.availableWidth
            height: implicitHeight
            radius: 10
            color: '#E7CACC'
            border.width: 1
            border.color: "#000000"

            Rectangle {
                width: control.visualPosition * parent.width
                height: parent.height
                color: "#cc0000"
                radius: 10
            }

            Text {
                id:backgroundText
                text: "Slide to Send"
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 200
                font.pixelSize: 22
                color: "#ffffff"
                anchors{
                    centerIn: parent
                }
            }
        }

        handle: Rectangle {
            id: sliderHandle
            property int fnValu : control.leftPadding  + control.visualPosition * (control.availableWidth- width)
            x: control.leftPadding  + control.visualPosition * (control.availableWidth- width)
            y: control.topPadding + control.availableHeight / 2 - height / 2
            implicitHeight: 70
            implicitWidth: 88
            radius: 10

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "ACT"
                font.pixelSize: 22
                color: '#ffffff'
            }

            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: '#990000' }
                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: '#cc0000' }
            }
        }
    }

    Label { // To display the countdown timer value.
        id: popupTimerLabel
        width: 428
        text: "SOS will send in "+popupCountdown+"Seconds"
        color: "#cc0000"
        font.pixelSize: 40
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignLeft
    }
}
```

TonTimerSingle.qml

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.9

Timer {
    id: root

    property int countdown: 0

    interval: 1000
    running: countdown > 0
    repeat: true

    signal quietModeTriggered

    onTriggered: {
        console.error("Countdown Value=====>", popupCountdown)
        countdown --;
        quietModeTriggered()
        console.error("==========TimerTriggered")
    }
}
```

I have followed the link and example to create a singleton qml timer  http://imaginativethinking.ca/make-qml-component-singleton and created a qmldir with following lines **singleton TonTimer 1.0 TonTimerSingle.qml**
but facing the following errors in various instances
--> :-1 pragma Singleton used with a non composite singleton type SingleTonTimer
--> Composite Singleton Type TonTimer is not creatable.

And firing a signal from ActPopup when popup close button is pressed, i guess the popup is getting destroyed even before the signal is fired or reached the other qml.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Singleton is not composed of two words. Anyway, did you use [qmlRegisterSingletonType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType-3) to register your type in `main.cpp`? If not, you must first do so or use a `qmldir` file.
Also, what is the strange import (`import "qrc:/timerFile"`) on top of the main?

Comment: Hello @SMR, i have already created qmldir file with singleton TonTimer 1.0 TonTimerSingle.qml and tried to follow the exampled found in http://imaginativethinking.ca/make-qml-component-singleton/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you are attempting to create an instance of `TonTimerSingle` in `main.qml`, which is incorrect. Try it like this `TonTimer.running`, but I couldn't locate the `countdown` property, where it is defined?

Comment: You can't create an instance of a QML singleton. You need to reference the existing instance by using its type name. (e.g. `TonTimer.running`)

Comment: @SMR, the countdown property is some thing i want to initialize the value for timer when slider is dragged until the end. I.e if i initialize the countdown value as 10 then timer should start counting down and when value reaches 0 it should emit a signal.

Comment: @user19012733 Ok, But, where did you define it? There wasn't any `property int countdown` that I could locate.